# Cannot Infer Type Variables for Collectors.toMap

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm trying to create an `EnumMap` that simply maps the enum's constants to their respective ordinals. I figured I could do so succinctly like so:

```
private static Map<Rank, Integer> defaultRankOrdering = new EnumMap<>(
    Arrays.stream(Rank.values()).collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Function::identity, e -> e.ordinal())));
```

However, the compiler says it cannot infer any of the type variables for `toMap`. I don't see why, considering that, per the two-argument signature of `toMap`:

```
public static <T, K ,U> Collector<T, ? ,Map<K, U>> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                                                         Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper)
```

`T` should be inferred to be `Rank`, as `Arrays.stream(Rank.values())` is a `Stream<Rank>`, `K` should also be inferred to be `Rank`, as `Function.identity` returns a `Function<T, T>`, and `U` should be inferred to be `Integer` because the return type of `Enum.ordinal` is `int`, which should be boxed to `Integer` in this case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `Function.identity()`, not `Function::identity` :

```
private static Map<Rank, Integer> defaultRankOrdering = new EnumMap<>(
    Arrays.stream(Rank.values()).collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), e -> e.ordinal())));
```

The type of `Function::identity` is `Supplier<Function<T,T>>`, since it's a method reference for a method that takes nothing and returns a `Function<T,T>`.

What you need for your key mapping function is a `Function<T,T>`, which is returned by simply calling the method `Function.identity()`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I'm quite new to Java, and mistakes like this are still very hard to catch.

Answer (score 3):

Even if @Eran has pointed out your problem, but I think you need this code snippet, so write it down in my answer:

```
static Map<Rank, Integer>
defaultRankOrdering = Arrays.stream(Rank.values()).collect(toMap(
        Function.identity(),
        Enum::ordinal,
        (v1, v2) -> v1, // it'is never be used, only support for create an EnumMap
        () -> new EnumMap<>(Rank.class)
));
```

Comment: I was considering using the four-argument method, but for some bizarre reason, I was operating under the assumption that the third argument, which is never used, would be more wasteful than using the `EnumMap<K, V>(Map<K, V> map)` constructor. Now that I think about it, it's obviously the other way around.

Comment: @IsaacSaffold Hi, the 3rd parameter is for merging values with same key, but for the `Enum.values()` there is no duplicated keys, so you can make it simply, and it never be called. it looks like take a bit more code, but the toMap with 4 parameters algorithm complexity is `O(N)` and  yours is `O(2N)` .

Comment: Right. I must be tired.